# how to save serial data stream to sql database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I'm having an issue to store data from my arduino weather shield. I'm getting the data as an array and converting it to string, but my problem is storing it, I double checked the connection to ms sql and it works fine.I think the problem is in the timeStamp, but i don't know how to fix it

this is the main code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;
using weathertest.Serial;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Timers;




namespace weathertest 
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        serialmanager _spManager;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            UserInitialization();
            _spManager.StartListening();
        }

        private void UserInitialization()
        {
            _spManager = new serialmanager();
            serialconfig mySerialSettings = _spManager.CurrentSerialSettings;
            serialSettingsBindingSource.DataSource = mySerialSettings;


            _spManager.NewSerialDataRecieved += new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved);
            this.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(MainForm_FormClosing);
        }



        private void MainForm_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            _spManager.Dispose();
        }
        public static String GetTimestamp(DateTime value) {
            return value.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss");//yyyyMMddHHmmssffff
        }
        void _spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved(object sender, SerialDataEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.InvokeRequired)
            {
                // Using this.Invoke causes deadlock when closing serial port, and BeginInvoke is good practice anyway.
                this.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<SerialDataEventArgs>(_spManager_NewSerialDataRecieved), new object[] { sender, e });
                return;
            }

            int maxTextLength = 1000; // maximum text length in text box
            if (tbData.TextLength > maxTextLength)
                tbData.Text = tbData.Text.Remove(0, tbData.TextLength - maxTextLength);

            // This application is connected to a GPS sending ASCCI characters, so data is converted to text
            string str = e.Data;
            tbData.AppendText(str);
            tbData.ScrollToCaret();
            string strValue = str;
            string[] strArray = strValue.Split(' ');

            try
            {

                foreach (object obj in strArray)
                {
                    string constring = "Data Source=BASHKIM;Initial Catalog=Weather;Integrated Security=True";
                    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
                    conn.Open();
                    String timeStamp = GetTimestamp(DateTime.Now);

                    label1.Text =  (strArray[0]);
                    label2.Text =  (strArray[1]);
                    label3.Text =  (strArray[2]);
                    label4.Text =  (strArray[3]);
                    label5.Text =  (strArray[4]);
                    label6.Text =  (strArray[5]);
                    label7.Text =  (strArray[6]);
                    label8.Text =  (strArray[7]);
                    label9.Text =  (strArray[8]);
                    label10.Text = (strArray[9]);
                    label11.Text = (strArray[10]);
                    label12.Text = (strArray[11]);
                    label13.Text = (strArray[12]);
                    label14.Text = (strArray[13]);
                    label15.Text = (strArray[14]);
                    label16.Text = timeStamp;




                    string query1 = @"INSERT INTO daily (winddir,windspeedmph,windgustdir,windspdmph_avg2m,windgustdir_10m,winddir_avg2m,humidity,tempf,rainin,dailyrainin,pressure,batt_lvl,light_lvl,timeStamp) values ("
      + label1.Text + "," + label2.Text + "," + label3.Text + "," + label4.Text + "," + label5.Text + "," + label6.Text + "," + label7.Text + "," + label8.Text + "," + label9.Text + "," + label10.Text + "," + label11.Text + "," + label12.Text + "," + label3.Text + "," + label14.Text + "," + label16.Text + ")";
                    conn.Close();
                }
                    richD.AppendText(str);
                    richD.ScrollToCaret();


            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); 
            }



        }


        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _spManager.StartListening();
        }

        private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'weatherDataSet2.daily' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
            //this.dailyTableAdapter.Fill(this.weatherDataSet2.daily);
            // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'weatherDataSet.daily' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
          //  this.dailyTableAdapter.Fill(this.weatherDataSet.daily);


        }
    }
}
```

and this is my database:

[image: Databasefoto]

hope someone can help

Comment: Given that almost all of the values you are storing are numeric, why are you storing everything as strings?

Comment: `foreach (object obj in strArray)`, why do you do this? you don't use `obj` all this will do is make you write 14 copies in to the database. Also, switch to parametriazed queries, it is much easier to work with.

Comment: That's a large amount of code. Can't you narrow it down? See http://sscce.org.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain what do you prefer me using instead of foreach

Comment: Nothing, i see no need for any looping at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`query1` is a string. It contains SQL. You forgot to execute the SQL in that string. You'll need to create a [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and execute it.

```
using(var cmd = new SqlCommand(query1, conn))
{
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

As an aside:

You should store numeric data using numeric types in your database, otherwise querying your data will be a massive PITA.

Your data seems to be taking a very strange path. First you copy it to the UI. Then you copy it from the UI to the database. Why not copy the data once to the UI, once to the database?

You're updating your UI in a tight loop, on the UI thread. This won't update your UI, because your UI thread is busy in the loop.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably submit this code to http://codereview.stackexchange.com. You can make this code much more efficient. Here is an example of the way you can create an SqlCommand. There will be no need to close your sql connection, the using statement takes care of it.

```
        using (conn)
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter query = new SqlDataAdapter();
            query.InsertCommand = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO daily (winddir,windspeedmph,windgustdir,windspdmph_avg2m,windgustdir_10m,winddir_avg2m,humidity,tempf,rainin,dailyrainin,pressure,batt_lvl,light_lvl,timeStamp) values "+
                                                                   "(@winddir,@windspeedmph,@windgustdir,@windspdmph_avg2m,@windgustdir_10m,@winddir_avg2m,@humidity,@tempf,@rainin,@dailyrainin,@pressure,@batt_lvl,@light_lvl,@timeStamp)",conn);

            query.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@winddir", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = (strArray[0]);
            query.InsertCommand.Parameters.Add("@windspeedmph", SqlDbType.NChar).Value = (strArray[1]); 


            query.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
```

Also try to use nvarchar rather then nchar for SQL datatype due to nvarchar being variable length. this will utilize less space in the DB.

And dont use timeStamp datatype for your timestamp. TimeStamp datatype is deceiving, use dateTime and set its default value to getDate() (so the program doesn't have to do extra work)

it may even be depreciated http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260631(v=sql.80).aspx